# Destroy current spawned GameObject NOT Entire prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My instantiations stop after 1 or 2 spawns, but I want them to keep spawning forever thru the game..

It's because I have the destroy piece of code in this script, but what can I do I need them to die after collision or there will be hundreds on screen like before. As usual when dead an enemy must die and disappear. So what do I do? The destroy code is destroying the entire enemy player /prefab not just the dead instance like I want.

I want the enemies to keep spawning but of course when killed by player they must disappear.

2d game I have this script on the enemy prefab and in scene enemies

I want the enemy on screen to die one by one when collision but the destroy is killing the entire object / prefab I think and it will not instantiate /spawn any more

I do have a few scripts on the enemy here is the instantiation script

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

```
public class spn2 : MonoBehaviour {

  GameObject Enemy;
//public GameObject EasyEnemey;
    public GameObject MediumEnemey;
    public GameObject HardEnemey;
    public Transform[] SpawnPoints;
    public float TimeBetweenSpawns;
    public int NumberOfEnemiesToSpawn;
    public int NumberOfMediumEnemiesToSpawn;
    public float EasyChance;
    public float MediumChance;
    public float HardChance;

    private int waveNumber;
    private float spawnTimer;
    private int numberOfEnemies;
    private int numberOfMediumEnemies;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //this below is the time to spawn so if 4 , every 4 seconds 1 will spawn  etc
        this.spawnTimer = 3.0f;
        this.waveNumber = 0;
        float totalChance = this.EasyChance + this.MediumChance + this.HardChance;
        if(Mathf.Abs(totalChance-1.0f)>0.0001f) { 
            Debug.LogWarning("Warning: The chances should add up to 1.0 ("+totalChance+" currently)");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void  Update()
    {
        this.spawnTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(this.spawnTimer<=0.0f)
        {
            Transform spawnPoint = this.SpawnPoints[Random.Range(0, this.SpawnPoints.Length)];
            Vector2 spawnPos = spawnPoint.position;
            Quaternion spawnRot = spawnPoint.rotation;
            switch(this.waveNumber)
            {
            case 0:
                //Instantiate(EasyEnemey, spawnPos,spawnRot);
            Instantiate(Resources.Load(Enemy) as GameObject, spawnPos, spawnRot);

                this.numberOfEnemies++;
                if(this.numberOfEnemies>=this.NumberOfEnemiesToSpawn)
                {
                    this.waveNumber++;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                Instantiate(MediumEnemey, spawnPos, spawnRot);
                this.numberOfMediumEnemies++;
                if (this.numberOfMediumEnemies >= this.NumberOfMediumEnemiesToSpawn)
                {
                    this.waveNumber++;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                float randomFloat = Random.value;
                if(randomFloat<this.EasyChance)
                {
                    Instantiate(Enemy, spawnPos, spawnRot);
                }
                else if(randomFloat<this.EasyChance+this.MediumChance)
                {
                    Instantiate(MediumEnemey, spawnPos, spawnRot);
                }
                else
                {
                    Instantiate(HardEnemey, spawnPos, spawnRot);
                }
                break;
            }
            this.spawnTimer = this.TimeBetweenSpawns;

        Destroy (gameObject, .7f);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is gameObject in this line? `Destroy (gameObject, .7f);`

Comment: do u mean what this script is on?  this script is on the enemy prefab and the enemy copies in the scene of the prefab..........  if you mean what that code line is for  its to destroy the enemy , I cant have the enemy floating around .... forever ,  I am instantiating constant enemies so there will be thousand in a minute or so,, keep in mind these are enemies that will be instantiated and fly thru screen constantly and player must try to kill as many as possible, enemies are never ending forever spawned.

Comment: any ideas? im still stuck on this?  ive tried everyuthing and watched tutorials

Comment: At this point, can you restate which problems you're still having? Does destroy still destroy the prefab? Are you having spawning issues?

Comment: yes I think its destroying the prefab

Comment: i have used a off-screen instance (tried) but these enemies have moving scripts on them .......i put a off-screen object like you said but all the objects have a moving script since the enemy's point is to fly thru the screen so player tries to kill as many enemies as he can so if I take off the moving script they do spawn constantly but when I put the move script on they die and do not spawn, and again I need them to move thru the screen, so im stuck I still cant figure this one out

Comment: please anyone help

Answer (score 3):

You are instantiating the prefab as your actual object, so when you delete your instance, you are deleting your prefab.  Try this code for the initialization instead. This will create a copy of the prefab and load it as an instance.

```
GameObject enemy = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Name of your prefab here") as GameObject, spawnPos, spawnRot);
```

For your other problem, where your things start spawning, let's take a look at your code. I've removed some things that aren't relevant, but I just copy and pasted from your stuff.  Look at what your code is doing.

Every update (called by Unity continuously, we can approximate as once every frame), we call this method, Update. It subtracts some time from SpawnTimer, so let's say your spawn timer was 4 seconds, and Time.DeltaTime for example, is 1 second (it isn't, but it's an example).

So your update will run 4 times, that's great, but what happens now? Suddenly, your spawn timer is 0, and this condition

```
if(this.spawnTimer<=0.0f)
```

evaluates to True, so we are ready to instantiate an enemy. Great. We go through the switch statement, select our enemy, create them, and then we call Destroy, which immediately deletes our gameObject.

```
public class spn2 : MonoBehaviour {
    //variables here that I removed
    //removed start method

    // Update is called once per frame
    void  Update()
    {
        this.spawnTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if(this.spawnTimer<=0.0f)
        {
            //instantiation stuff;
            {
            case 0:
                Instantiate(Resources.Load(Enemy) as GameObject, spawnPos, spawnRot);
                break;
            case 1:
                Instantiate(MediumEnemey, spawnPos, spawnRot);
                break;
            case 2:
                //instantiation logic
                break;
            }
            this.spawnTimer = this.TimeBetweenSpawns;

        Destroy (gameObject, .7f);  <-- Destroy is here? This is your problem!
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Replace this code that you have `Instantiate(EasyEnemey, spawnPos,spawnRot);` with `Instantiate(Resources.Load("Name of your prefab here") as GameObject, spawnPos, spawnRot);` Make sure to add the prefabs name into the Load.

Comment: do I replace it with that everywhere? I have it many places  not just one

Comment: Well, try it in one place, create an easy enemy, delete it, see if it works, and then if it does, replace your instantiate calls everywhere.

Comment: ok and do I have to change the beginning  public variable prefab name also? I think so correct ?

Comment: You can keep the name, just assign to it, like so:
`EasyEnemey = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Name of Easy enemy prefab here") as GameObject, spawnPos, spawnRot);`

Comment: im getting 3 errors when I changed to what you said

Comment: this is what I changed to

Comment: just tried that another way and still getting errors

Comment: errors  are       Assets/water/spn2.cs(46,45): error CS0118: `Enemy' is a `type' but a `variable' was expected

Comment: Assets/water/spn2.cs(46,45): error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected

Comment: Assets/water/spn2.cs(46,18): error CS0311: The type `<error>' cannot be used as type parameter `T' in the generic type or method `UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate<T>(T, UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Quaternion)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from `<error>' to `UnityEngine.Object'

Comment: Ok, 1) You need to add quotes around your name, so Resources.Load(Enemy) needs to be Resources.Load("Enemy"). 2) you need to assign the result to your objects at the top of the class, so don't forget the `EasyEnemey = ` part in from of the code.
`

Comment: ok it plays now but it doesn't work same result nothing spawns after a few

Comment: this is what I changed to so far  and doesn't work       Quaternion spawnRot = spawnPoint.rotation;
   switch(this.waveNumber)
   {
   case 0:
    //Instantiate(EasyEnemey, spawnPos,spawnRot);
    EasyEnemey = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Enemy") as GameObject, spawnPos, spawnRot);

    this.numberOfEasyEnemies++;
    if(this.numberOfEasyEnemies>=this.NumberOfEasyEnemiesToSpawn)
    {
     this.waveNumber++;
    }

Comment: Do you know what Debug.Log is? You have to debug your code. Put Debug.Log inside all  the switch/case statement and make sure that your Instantiate code executes.

Comment: not to good with debug  do I add it just like that below the new code snip we changed?

Comment: @matt Take a look at my answer. It fixes so many problems. Please understand that I have no idea what you are doing. What I just did is to fix the problem that destroys your original prefab without `Resources.Load`. If you still can't get this to work with my solution then I suggest you learn the basic. Follow a project tutorial from [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials). Finish that tutorial then continue working on your project.

Comment: @Programmer   it didn't work it still doesn't spawn after a while,   I want to be clear again, I do have 2 other destroy scripts on the enemys though    should I reference the tempenemy in those also? I tried but got errors

Comment: "ok it plays now but it doesn't work same result nothing spawns after a few ". I'm not sure what the issue here is anymore. Are your prefabs being destroyed when the object is despawned?

Also, if things aren't spawning, take a look at your code. In Update method (this is called continuously by Unity), you have a spawnTime variable that you are subtracting from. Then when your enemies spawn is zero or less, you try to instantiate it, and THEN in EVERY case you call `Destroy (gameObject, .7f);`, so basically, eventually you create an object and destroy it in the same frame.

Comment: @matt Follw the tutorials in my answer. When you finish it, you will be able to continue with the script I provided. You need to understand the basics before working on your game. I don't think there is amount of help other than that that will solve your problem.

Comment: @Programmer please note I am not looking for shortcuts ,,, I did follow all those tuts  I just finished the spaceship one but the destroy only shows how to destroy on leaving screen  not instance like I need   --- I do understand somewhat of what im doing its just some things like this that stop me in tracks , I have checked those tuts out already but I dont see how to create a instance and destroy the instance not the original prefab

Comment: just to note  I need a destroy script so the instantiations get destroyed , I know the destroy code is the issue but what do I do?  I need it.